# programming in C with GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I have a problem with a program in C. I have that modifies a file .wav to reserve a amount of memory, the file .wav is an argument of the main program. The code is the following:

The library mula.h is the following:

#ifndef _MULAW_H_
  #define _MULAW_H_

static int16 muLaw[256] = {
 -0x1f5f, -0x1e5f, -0x1d5f, -0x1c5f, -0x1b5f, -0x1a5f, -0x195f, -0x185f,
 -0x175f, -0x165f, -0x155f, -0x145f, -0x135f, -0x125f, -0x115f, -0x105f,
 -0x0f9f, -0x0f1f, -0x0e9f, -0x0e1f, -0x0d9f, -0x0d1f, -0x0c9f, -0x0c1f,
 -0x0b9f, -0x0b1f, -0x0a9f, -0x0a1f, -0x099f, -0x091f, -0x089f, -0x081f,
 -0x07bf, -0x077f, -0x073f, -0x06ff, -0x06bf, -0x067f, -0x063f, -0x05ff,
 -0x05bf, -0x057f, -0x053f, -0x04ff, -0x04bf, -0x047f, -0x043f, -0x03ff,
 -0x03cf, -0x03af, -0x038f, -0x036f, -0x034f, -0x032f, -0x030f, -0x02ef,
 -0x02cf, -0x02af, -0x028f, -0x026f, -0x024f, -0x022f, -0x020f, -0x01ef,
 -0x01d7, -0x01c7, -0x01b7, -0x01a7, -0x0197, -0x0187, -0x0177, -0x0167,
 -0x0157, -0x0147, -0x0137, -0x0127, -0x0117, -0x0107, -0x00f7, -0x00e7,
 -0x00db, -0x00d3, -0x00cb, -0x00c3, -0x00bb, -0x00b3, -0x00ab, -0x00a3,
 -0x009b, -0x0093, -0x008b, -0x0083, -0x007b, -0x0073, -0x006b, -0x0063,
 -0x005d, -0x0059, -0x0055, -0x0051, -0x004d, -0x0049, -0x0045, -0x0041,
 -0x003d, -0x0039, -0x0035, -0x0031, -0x002d, -0x0029, -0x0025, -0x0021,
 -0x001e, -0x001c, -0x001a, -0x0018, -0x0016, -0x0014, -0x0012, -0x0010,
 -0x000e, -0x000c, -0x000a, -0x0008, -0x0006, -0x0004, -0x0002,  0x0000,
  0x1f5f,  0x1e5f,  0x1d5f,  0x1c5f,  0x1b5f,  0x1a5f,  0x195f,  0x185f,
  0x175f,  0x165f,  0x155f,  0x145f,  0x135f,  0x125f,  0x115f,  0x105f,
  0x0f9f,  0x0f1f,  0x0e9f,  0x0e1f,  0x0d9f,  0x0d1f,  0x0c9f,  0x0c1f,
  0x0b9f,  0x0b1f,  0x0a9f,  0x0a1f,  0x099f,  0x091f,  0x089f,  0x081f,
  0x07bf,  0x077f,  0x073f,  0x06ff,  0x06bf,  0x067f,  0x063f,  0x05ff,
  0x05bf,  0x057f,  0x053f,  0x04ff,  0x04bf,  0x047f,  0x043f,  0x03ff,
  0x03cf,  0x03af,  0x038f,  0x036f,  0x034f,  0x032f,  0x030f,  0x02ef,
  0x02cf,  0x02af,  0x028f,  0x026f,  0x024f,  0x022f,  0x020f,  0x01ef,
  0x01d7,  0x01c7,  0x01b7,  0x01a7,  0x0197,  0x0187,  0x0177,  0x0167,
  0x0157,  0x0147,  0x0137,  0x0127,  0x0117,  0x0107,  0x00f7,  0x00e7,
  0x00db,  0x00d3,  0x00cb,  0x00c3,  0x00bb,  0x00b3,  0x00ab,  0x00a3,
  0x009b,  0x0093,  0x008b,  0x0083,  0x007b,  0x0073,  0x006b,  0x0063,
  0x005d,  0x0059,  0x0055,  0x0051,  0x004d,  0x0049,  0x0045,  0x0041,
  0x003d,  0x0039,  0x0035,  0x0031,  0x002d,  0x0029,  0x0025,  0x0021,
  0x001e,  0x001c,  0x001a,  0x0018,  0x0016,  0x0014,  0x0012,  0x0010,
  0x000e,  0x000c,  0x000a,  0x0008,  0x0006,  0x0004,  0x0002,  0x0000,
};

#endif

The code in C is the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef int16_t int16;

 #include "mulaw.h"

/* This function reads 8 bit samples from fIn, decodes them
  * from G.711Mu into pcm_s16be, and writes them into fOut.
 */
void decodeFile(FILE * fIn, FILE * fOut, uint32_t samples) {

uint32_t i;

uint8_t * inSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(uint8_t));
int16_t * outSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(int16_t));

fread(inSamples, sizeof(uint8_t), samples, fIn);

for (i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    outSamples[i] = 4 * muLaw[inSamples[i]];
}

fwrite(outSamples, sizeof(int16_t), samples, fOut);

free(inSamples);
free(outSamples);
  }

 #define MAX_FILE_SIZE 256

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
/* Data structures needed later */
char inputFile[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
char outputFile[MAX_FILE_SIZE];

FILE * fIn = NULL, * fOut = NULL;

struct header_t {
    char ChunkID[4];
    int32_t ChunkSize;
    char    Format[4];
} header;

char SubchunkID[4];
uint32_t SubchunkSize;

struct subheader_t {
    int16_t AudioFormat;
    int16_t NumChannels;
    int32_t SampleRate;
    int32_t ByteRate;
    int16_t BlockAlign;
    int16_t BitsPerSample;
    int16_t ExtraParamSize;
    int16_t Padding;
} subheader;



/* Usage */
if (argc != 3) {
    puts("Usage is: mulaw INFILE OUTFILE\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Careful here!!!!! */
strncpy(inputFile, argv[1], MAX_FILE_SIZE);
strncpy(outputFile, argv[2], MAX_FILE_SIZE);

/* Open input file */
fIn = fopen (inputFile, "rb");

/* Read main header */
fread(&header, sizeof(struct header_t), 1, fIn);

if (memcmp(header.ChunkID, "RIFF", 4) != 0
    || memcmp(header.Format, "WAVE", 4) != 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown input format\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Read sub header */

while (fread(SubchunkID, sizeof(SubchunkID), 1, fIn)) {
    fread(&SubchunkSize, sizeof(SubchunkSize), 1, fIn);

    printf("Reading chunk of type %c%c%c%c (%d bytes)\n", 
        isprint(SubchunkID[0]) ? SubchunkID[0] : '?',
        isprint(SubchunkID[1]) ? SubchunkID[1] : '?',
        isprint(SubchunkID[2]) ? SubchunkID[2] : '?',
        isprint(SubchunkID[3]) ? SubchunkID[3] : '?',
        (int) SubchunkSize);

    if (memcmp(SubchunkID, "fmt ", 4) == 0) {
        /* read a fmt_ header */
        fread(&subheader, SubchunkSize, 1, fIn);

        /* we are going to adjust this header now to change the audio format */
        if (subheader.AudioFormat != 7) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Only mu-law audio input is supported\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* adjust audio format and bit depth */
        subheader.AudioFormat = 1;
        subheader.BitsPerSample = 16;

        /* fix derivative fields */
        subheader.ByteRate = subheader.SampleRate * subheader.NumChannels * subheader.BitsPerSample / 8;
        subheader.BlockAlign = subheader.NumChannels * subheader.BitsPerSample / 8;

        /* we don't write ExtraParamSize, because for AudioFormat == 1 it is not needed */
        SubchunkSize -= 2;

        /* Open file and write the header for our updated fmt_ chunk */
        fOut = fopen (outputFile, "wb");
        fwrite(&header, sizeof(struct header_t), 1, fOut);  /* Main header */

        fwrite(SubchunkID, sizeof(SubchunkID), 1, fOut);    /* Subheader */
        fwrite(&SubchunkSize, sizeof(SubchunkSize), 1, fOut);
        fwrite(&subheader, SubchunkSize, 1, fOut);

    } else if (memcmp(SubchunkID, "data", 4) == 0) {
        /* here is our mu-law data */

        /* write the header for our new chunk (it is twice as large) */
        int32_t tSubchunkSize = SubchunkSize * 2;
        fwrite(SubchunkID, sizeof(SubchunkID), 1, fOut);
        fwrite(&tSubchunkSize, sizeof(SubchunkSize), 1, fOut);

        /* process the data */

        (fIn, fOut, SubchunkSize);
    } else {
        /* unknown chunk, skipping */
        fseek(fIn, SubchunkSize, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}

/* Cleanup and exit */
fclose(fIn);
fclose(fOut);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the following: In the program in C we see the reserve of memory in line 31 is the following: uint8_t * inSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(uint8_t)); This reserve of memory is done in relation to a variable of the archive to decode. We realize to produce a segmentation fault beacuse it needs a lot of resources to open. I have to modify a file  example-fileM1F1-mulaw-Afsp.wav  to reserve 1073741824 bytes in the line 31 of the program.
I don't know to do it.

Comment: The problem is the following: In the program in C we see the reserve of memory in line 31 is the following: uint8_t * inSamples = malloc(samples * sizeof(uint8_t)); This reserve of memory is done in relation to a variable of the archive to decode. We realize to produce a segmentation fault beacuse it needs a lot of resources to open. I have to modify a file  example-fileM1F1-mulaw-Afsp.wav  to reserve 1073741824 bytes in the line 31 of the program.
I don't know to do it. Furthermore I have to fill this table: File offset, Old value and New value

Comment: I think you have a little/big endian problem as `1073741824 = 0x40000000`. Maybe you read a big endian word that you have to swap to allocate `0x40` bytes !!